# TU3-DS2 dock not working in Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, usb

I have a laptop and two monitors, now I have bought the **Trendnet Universal USB 3.0 Docking Station TU3-DS2** because I would like to use my two external monitors. At first glance it's not working since there is not output to the monitors. So I have run the command `lsusb` to find out what's new on my PC with the dock connected/non connected and here are the results:

```
Dock non connected
--
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:0670 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Docke connected
--
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:0670 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub  ===> this is new here
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 17e9:4307 DisplayLink ===> this is new here
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2109:2811 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub ===> this is new here
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The thing is I can't find a driver or a way to make this work, can I get some help?

Answer (score 1):

Try the drivers here: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

They're only packaged for Ubuntu, but there are instructions for extracting the files from the archive to repackage them for other distros.

I found those from comments on Amazon regarding drivers for similar docks.